# Package-scoped fixtures in pytest 2.3

Tags: python, pytest

In the latest release of pytest, it is easy to create fixtures that are function, class, module or session-scoped like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module") 
def db():
     return DB()
```

That creates a fixture that is going to be called only once for each python module in which it is used.

But what about fixtures that need to be called once per python package ? 
(With nose, it can be done using setUp/tearDown methods in the `__init__.py` of the package)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For package or directory-level fixtures, you can declare a fixture in a `conftest.py` file in the directory where you need it, using `scope='session'`.  The fixture will be instantiated once the first test in the package/directory uses it.  Here is [an example](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#package-directory-level-fixtures-setups) However, if the fixture function registers a finalizer, you might see it executing not directly after the last test in that directory.  I think pytest could be made to support more eager teardown or introduce a "directory" scope if needed.  Usually it's not a big problem if the teardown executes a little later as long as it doesn't execute too early :)  Note also that apparently Jason [intends to drop package-level setup/teardown support for nose](http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/differences.html)

Anyway, if you have a need for more eager/exact pytest teardown, please feel free to [open an issue](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issues/new).

Comment: I think directory based scoping is bad idea cause a package could have multiple directories. Package-level could make more sense, but even then, I am not certain.

Comment: now in 2018, I noticed package scope supported has been added to fixture. But as you mentioned,  if the fixture function registers a finalizer, it is executed not directly after the last test in that directory.  That's not the expected behavior for package level teardown.  I think Robotframework implements setup teardown in the way more easy to understand.